# What does |= in java mean?

Tags: java, operators

This is used in an android notification here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html#notificationmanager_configure

```
// Hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: [Logical OR](http://www.erpgreat.com/java/java-boolean-logical-operators.htm) and assignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitwise OR with assignment.

```
int a = 6, b = 5;
a = a | b;
// is equivalent to
a |= b;
```

In systems like Android, it often makes sense to compress many different boolean properties into a single integer value. Values can be combined with `|` and tested with `&`.

```
// invented constants for example
public static final int HAS_BORDER = 1;   // in binary: 0b00000001
public static final int HAS_FRAME = 2;    //            0b00000010
public static final int HAS_TITLE = 4;    //            0b00000100

public void exampleMethod() {
  int flags = 0;                          //    flags = 0b00000000
  flags |= HAS_BORDER;                    //            0b00000001
  flags |= HAS_TITLE;                     //            0b00000101

  if ((flags & HAS_BORDER) != 0) {
    // do x
  }

  if ((flags & HAS_TITLE) != 0) {
    // do y
  }
}
```

Comment: `a = a | b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`?

Answer (score 4):

Same as:

```
noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

All the bits are `OR`'ed together.  It's usually a good way to *add on* a flag to a set of existing flags, since `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` probably just has one bit set, so that bit will be *turned on* in `noti.flags`.